# Does Google Maps Android API work in release mode?

Tags: android, authentication, google-maps-api-3, fingerprint

I have done this steps to try to make work Google Maps Android API:
1) Enable “Google Maps Android API”
2) Get SHA1 fingerprints of my production and debug keystores. Debug keystore is usually available in /Users/myusername/.android/debug.keystore directory.
3) In Google Developers Console -> APIs & auth -> Credentials. I have created a new key for Android applications and add certificate SHA1 fingerprint and package name for my debug and release certificates.
4) Finally I have added the API key to maps_api_key parameter. 
But I still don't see map to show up. What else could I been missing?

Thanks for your help

This is error Im getting:

`01-07 11:34:03.928 2513-4480/com.app.name E/b: Authentication failed on the server.
01-07 11:34:03.928 2513-4480/com.app.name E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
01-07 11:34:03.958 2513-4480/com.app.name E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
                                                                                        Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
                                                                                        Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
                                                                                            API Key: AIzaSyD7dCGyDaJlmpmu-vWglqxGwqHnqXXx9xx
                                                                                            Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): 90:20:70:19:C8:D9:7E:30:4C:54:73:50:B8:DE:10:BB:93:00:86:66;com.app.name`

Comment: Are you sure your signing the release apk with the correct key?  What are you building the app with, gradle or maven?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does work on release mode. Only thing you need to do is generate sha finger print from release keystore instead of default debug keystore.